# Writing pandas dataframe headers in one column in excel

Tags: python, excel, pandas

i have a big csv file which i cannot open in excel, but somehow I need to sort it further in excel and for this i only need the column headers of my frame, so far i got with a pandas dataframe:

```
cols = df.columns.tolist()
```

which leads to a long list of column names:

```
['ID',
 'ABUNG KZ',
 'ABSTIMMKS',
 'BETR ABWEBUEHR',
 'BETR ABWITEN',
 'AGR ',
 'ANSCH',
 'ANSCHRIFT',
 ...
]
```

How can I write this list into a excel file, that I have this in one column, all column names in a diffferent row so that it looks like (in excel):

```
Names
ID
ABUNG KZ
...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code:

```py
cols = df.columns.tolist()

data = {'Names': cols} 

df2 = pd.DataFrame(data)
df2.to_excel('df_excel.xlsx', index=False)
```